# monitor mouse status on Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, device-driver, macos-carbon

I wanted to monitor mouse status(connect/disconnect) in system wide on OS X. I checked the Apple developer library, but cannot find any clues.

My goal is to monitor both USB and Bluetooth mouse. Any API that I could use?

Thank you very much.

--N

Comment: There may be a couple different approaches to a solution, but first, this needs some clarification on your part: do you want to do this from a kernel extension (driver) or do you have an application (or tool, or background app, or whatever) where you want to do this monitoring?

Comment: I would like to do it in user mode app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use I/O Kit's HID manager API to find out when new HIDs (Human Interface Devices) appear in the system, or are disconnected from it.  This is a complex topic in itself, so I won't throw random code at you - just go read [Accessing a HID Device](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/new_api_10_5/tn2187.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970-CH214-SW2) (in particular the [Matching HID Devices](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/new_api_10_5/tn2187.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970-CH214-SW9) and [Registering for Unplug Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/new_api_10_5/tn2187.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970-CH214-SW69) sections).  Example code is included.